# RxJS 5 - finally, finalize, complete, none works

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a simple subscription, where i want to execute some more logic at the end (both in error and success cases, that is why i need a finally/complete behaviour). The subscription looks like this:

```
this.service.call(x)
 .subscribe(response => {
     ...
  }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     ...
  });
```

It is weird that i dont get the finally work.. i have tried a bunch of suggestions like

- finally(() => ...) before the .subscribe
- pipe(finalize()...) before the .subscribe
- a 3. callback in the current subscribe function..  (complete)
- .add(() => {
  }); after .subscribe

None of them worked for me until now.. What should i do?

Content of the weird call function (external dependency):

```
  public readDetails(id: string): Observable<Details> {
    return new Observable<Details>(subscriber => {
      this.appConfig.getEndpoint('details').subscribe(
        (endpoint: Endpoint) => {
          const url = `${endpoint.toUrl()}/${id}`;
          const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            ...
          });
          this.http.get<Details>(url, {headers})
            .subscribe(
              (response: Details) => {
                subscriber.next(response);
              },
              (error) => {
                subscriber.error(error);
              }
            );
        },
        error => subscriber.error(error)
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `call()` completes? Can you please share the code for `call()`.

Comment: actually when i let the method as it is, my subscribe (or error function) is called, and the app works correctly.. i will edit the question for the content of call function

Comment: the finally callback is called... finally, i.e. when the stream completes or errors. If it's an infinite stream, the finally callback will never been called. If you added a complete callback and it was never called, it means your stream is infinite (or at least that you didn't wait long enough to see it complete).

Comment: How/what should the readDetails function have returned a completion?

Comment: @akcasoy `subscriber.complete()`

Answer (score 2):

Your custom observable never completes, so your finally callback is never called.

You shouldn't create a custom observable just to chain two calls. Instead, learn to use the RxJS operators. I'm going to use the RxJS 6 syntax here since RxJS 5 is obsolete, but the translation shouldn't be hard:

```
return this.appConfig.getEndpoint('details').pipe(
  switchMap(endpoint => {
    const url = `${endpoint.toUrl()}/${id}`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        ...
    });
    return this.http.get<Details>(url, {headers});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. i have overwritten the my serviceCall.. still i dont get  the finally get work..  i have the error "finally is not a function".. i have also tried the 3. parameter in subscribe (complete part), it is also not called.. also pipe with finalize.. :/

Comment: i will write another question.. maybe i should formulate the main problem in another way

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment ([comments-57008755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008473/rxjs-5-finally-finalize-complete-none-works#comments-57008755)),

Before ***rxJs*** v5.5, it was called '**finally**'.

From v5.5 on, it was renamed to '**finalize**' (due to keyword restriction) because of the introduction of pipeable Operators which help with tree shaking.

See ([here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/pipeable-operators.md)) for the source info.